# selecting columns based on value in single column

Tags: mysql, select

I am complete newbie when it comes to MySQL. I have done some searching around here and elsewhere, but haven't been able to work out something that I imagine is very simple.

I have an email program that imports fields/columns from a MySQL database for bulk emails.

I am wanting to only import information for users that have a particular value in a particular column in a table.

To import all users I would normally use:

```
SELECT firstname, email FROM users
```

I have tried amending this to:

```
SELECT firstname, email FROM users WHERE group = "test"
```

where `group` is the name of the column that I am trying to test against, and `test` is the value I am searching for. I think this might be close, but it brings up an error.

Could someone put me straight?

Comment: Well... What you've described *should* work. What's the error you're getting? Is the column `group` in the `users` table? Is it of the same data type (CHAR) as `"test"`?

Comment: Next time post the error message in your question

Comment: Careful using double-quotes for string literals. ANSI specification uses double quotes for identifiers. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes

Comment: Thanks for the info.  There was no specific error message, probably because the software I am using for the bulk emails does not support it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is that group is a keyword in MySQL. You can use

```
SELECT firstname, email FROM users WHERE `group` = "test"
```

Use back ticks to quote field names.

Comment: Agreed; ideally, just use backticks to delimit _all_ field names as a matter of course. You'll make them more distinctive in your queries and avoid ever running into bugs like this, _some of which may in theory not cause a syntax error_.